# symbol lookup error: undefined symbol:

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, undefined-symbol

I have two libraries, `lib1.so` and `lib2.so`. `lib1.so` has a function `func1`. `libs2.so` uses this function `func1`.

Compilation works without problems.

But when starting a program with `libs2.so`, then it says, that `func1` is an undefined symbol. Wenn using the `ldd` tool, then it points to a file which exists. Ok, so I typed the commands `nm -D lib1.so | grep -i 'func1'` and `'nm -D lib2.so | grep -i 'func1'`.

There is one small difference: the `lib1.so` command shows something like that

```
00000000003e393c T XYZfunc1ZXYmm
```

The `libs2.so` command shows this

```
U XYZfunc1ZXY
```

As far as I know, the `U` for `lib2.so` stands for `Undefined`. 1) Am I right? What I also can see, that in the first output, there is a `mm` at the end. I thought this: As far as `func1` is part of a member `mm` is added to the symbol. 2) Is that correct? If yes, why does `lib2.so` does not find the symbol?

3) I've run out of ideas, how to solve this problem. Does anyone have an idea?

4) There might be another question: Lets assume I compiled `lib2.so`, which is dependent on `lib1.so`, like in this example. After compiling `libs2.so`, I recompile `lib1.so`, with some smaller changed, but all exported symbols are the same. Could a problem occurr like I described above?

Comment: did you tell lib2 that it's using lib1? it's not going to search every .so file on your system to try and find that system. you have to include lib1 while building lib2..

Comment: I am not sure but your name seems to be decorated. Please type nm -C -D lib1.so | grep -i 'func1' and `nm -C -D lib2.so | grep -i 'func1` As for the Q#4 - as long as your binary API is the same no (https://techbase.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C++)

Comment: One more thing. Fr the sake of simplicity you need to define your function like this: extern "C" { func1() } -- http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/thesolution.html

Comment: @MarcB: Before compiling there is a `configure` file. I looked into the `config.log` file and looking at the `LDFLAGS` it shows me that I said to `lib2`, he should use `lib1` through parameter `-l`.

Comment: @skwllsp: Yes, the function name was from me. It is because I do not want to give you the real function name and the real name of the function is not important. I only wrote down what I found out.